# Select Datetime field that equals now

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
 $SS = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $get_r = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE due_date LIKE '%$SS%'";
 $get_r_res = mysqli_query($conn,$get_r);
```

This does not return anything......but when I have this:

```
 $SS = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $get_r = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE due_date LIKE '%2018-09-16 12:08:00%'";
 $get_r_res = mysqli_query($conn,$get_r);
```

It works!!!!  What the heck!  What the heck am I missing?

Forgot the mention the date is datetime in the mysql database.
Thanks,
Will

Comment: Because, you're checking for today's date's "time" which isn't in your database yet, since you've gone over that time, not the date though. If you're looking for an exact record, use `=`, not LIKE.

Comment: Tried that before...The data that I am comparing to is in the database. Just comparing now to what is in the database.  Hope I explained that right.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for giving comments here as I can't add comments.

In first section just print your sql query.

```
$get_r = "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE due_date LIKE '%$SS%'";
echo $get_r;
```

You will get an idea what exact query is prepared and then compared with the second one.